# [Scons][Linker] Unable to find linker script

Tags: c, linker, scons

I'm trying to use scons to build a simple hello world project, explicitly setting the linker flags to read a custom linker script:

```
env.Append(LINKFLAGS = [
    '-T script/linker_script.ld'
    ])
```

The problem is that when this is run, SCons puts double quotes " " around the -T option, which results in something like this:

```
arm-none-eabi-ld -o bareMetalStartupScons.elf "-T script/linker_script.ld" src/main.o asm/startup.o
arm-none-eabi-ld: cannot open linker script file  script/linker_script.ld: No such file or directory
```

The script is there, and if I just remove the double quotes and run the command manually, it completes without errors, e.g.

```
arm-none-eabi-ld -T script/linker_script.ld src/main.o asm/startup.o
```

Any solution for this issue or any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I found a workaround for this issue, which is to specify the path of the linker script without any space from the -T, e.g.

```
env.Append(LINKFLAGS = [
    '-Tscript/linker_script.ld'
    ])
```

In this case SCons will not put the double quotes around the argument "as a string" when passing it to the executable.

Comment: Yes if there's a (white)space in the argument then SCons will quote it.  You could also do LINKFLAGS=['-T','script/linker_script.ld'].